# python requests library not returning any response

Tags: python, python-requests

When I try the following code, requests library not returning any response

```
import requests
url = "http://www.nodefarm.com/"
resp = requests.get(url, timeout=5.0)
print resp
```

Can someone tell me why my code got stuck in line 3?

P.S: I'm not receiving any error.

When I visit `http://www.nodefarm.com/` in my browser, site works fine

Comment: do you have the requests library installed? is the location of the install in your python path?

Comment: If he didn't, he would get an import error on line 1.  It wouldn't even make it to the line he gets stuck on.

Comment: @deweyredman Yes I have that library installed. I'm using that library for months. All other urls working except this one. Its just 3 lines of code. So you may test that in your shell.

Comment: Reason why I was asking is because context would be nice...For example is this is on a windows system and python hasn't been whitelisted through the firewall that might explain what's going on.

Comment: This helps, let me see if i can figure something out

Comment: Confirmed that I'm getting the same behavior.  I'll do a little more investigation to see ast o why

Comment: @deweyredman ifloop posted a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, the thing is, it's not exactly getting stuck.

that url returns an apparently endless stream of data, the first few lines of which look a bit like so:

```
ICY 200 OK
icy-notice1:<BR>This stream requires <a href="http://www.winamp.com/">Winamp</a><BR>
icy-notice2:SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.8<BR>
icy-name:RADIO HANG 106  FM BATAM - SVR USA
icy-genre:Misc
icy-url:http://live.hang106.com/;stream.nsv
content-type:audio/mpeg
icy-pub:1
icy-br:48
```

Pulling it up in vlc, it seems to be talk radio in a language I don't speak.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me how to handle this problem in my program?

Answer (score 4):

IfLoop is correct that the page is streaming data. You can use requests with `stream=True` and iterate to see the data for yourself:

```
import requests
url = "http://www.nodefarm.com/"
resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
for line in resp.iter_lines():
    if line:
        print line
```

Not sure how much this will help though.